# Join a Flat Table to an EAV Table with Magento?

Tags: collections, join, magento, model

I am trying to manke an Adminhtml Grid which joins a table that I made called "facility" to "customer_entity" and all of its attribtues.

I'm noticing that since my table is flat, and the model inherits fomr Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract, I'm not able to use all the class_methods that I've seen as examples on the backend.

I've successfully been able to join my table to the customer_entity table doing the following:

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('facility/facility')->getCollection()
                ->join('customer/entity', 'customer_id = entity_id');
```

However, what I really need is just to get the customer name. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customer names are not stored in one field, they are a combination of first, middle and last name; and depending on settings, a prefix and suffix too. The customer classes have methods for combining these for you.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
              ->addNameToSelect()
              ->joinTable('facility/facility', 'entity_id=customer_id', array('*'));
```

The `joinTable` method is part of EAV collections which is why you won't see it in the core MySQL4 based collections. The first parameter is not a literal table name but an entity table as described in your config.xml.

Comment: If I use this method, I got "Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id “xxx” already exist" error.

Comment: @piavgh your custom table contains more than one record for customer "xxx".  Make sure the column you are joining on is indexed as unique.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I agree with the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028827) just some corrections to the syntax

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                  ->addNameToSelect()
                  ->joinTable('facility/facility', 'customer_id=entity_id', array('*'), null, 'right');
```

null part is a WHERE clause and the 'right' is the type of the join

Or maybe a better decision is:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel("facility/facility")->getCollection()->getSelect()->join('customer_entity', 'entity_id=customer_id', array('*'));
```

Comment: In your second way, how to get customer name?